# jQuery AJAX issue

Tags: text, google-chrome, jquery, get

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click.function () {
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://example.com/api/index.php?action=login_user&app_key=APIKey&username=XXX&password=Pass',

        success: function(result) {
        if (result.error) {
        alert('My error message')
    } else {
        //use your result to display
        $("div").html(result);

    }
}
});
});

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div><h2>Text to be changed</h2></div>
```

Just downloaded jQuery after a million failed attempts (Same Origin Policy issue) at implementing AJAX using pure JS in Chrome.

In the above code, body consists of a button. When clicked, a request is made to the URL which responds with some Text (the URL does respond with text in IE 8 using pure JS). I am not getting any response from the URL using the above code. Please help. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like a call with an ajax structure. Your current does not fit into the jquery's style of calling ajax function.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click.function () {
 $.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/api/index.php?action=login_user&app_key=APIKey&username=XXX&password=Pass',

    success: function(result) {
        if (result == '') {
            alert('My error message');
        } else {
            //use your result to display

            document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = result;

        }
    }
  });
  });
  }); </script>
```

Okie, my bet..edited. BAsically, if the result is an error it will display an alert and if it is successful, you will populate the div tag with the result (it is already in html?) if its not, then  nothing happens. Your result must be return in html structure..

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your code is not working for me. When I click on the button, nothing happens. No error message.

Comment: @Meow edited take a look again. Also, make sure your url returns a html if you want to display in html. or else, nothing happens.

Comment: @pivotal developer, I edited my post to include the entire code. The URL should return plain text (log-in authentication code). So, it does not return HTML. Btw, the call is never a success. I tried an 'Alert' in both the if and else cases. I am not getting any alert.

Comment: @meow if you are using the code you display above, remove the extra script tag. you just need one of them.. remove <script type="text/javascript">

Comment: @pivotal developer - Yes. When I type in the URL in my browser I get a new page with just a string (plain-text) i.e the authentication code for log-in.

Comment: Removed the extra script tag. No use.

Comment: first, i tried to paste your url in my browser, i get nothing. are you sure thats the right url? Second, i have changed the code to insert result into your div html - go and try it and also add an id in the div tag like this <div id="div"></div>. i think you need to go and read up more on jquery or javascripts. no point pasting codes from here. important is you have to understand what they mean in the first place then u can modify other's people solution

Comment: It's not the 'real' URL. The real URL consists of username, password and my API key. So, I replaced those with random words like 'XXX', 'Pass' etc. But the real URL does return text.

Comment: Tried adding the tag. No use. The main problem is that the control never goes to IF or ELSE. I tried adding an Alert statement in both. Never executes.